# Hunspell error in emacs

Tags: flyspell, spell-checking, hunspell

My `.emacs` file contains the following code to make `hunspell` work, however I get the following error message when starting `flyspell-mode`:

```
Starting new Ispell process hunspell with deutsch-hunspell dictionary...
Error enabling Flyspell mode:
(ispell-phaf: No matching entry for deutsch-hunspell.
)
```

Any idea of how to fix this?

```
(add-to-list 'ispell-local-dictionary-alist '("deutsch-hunspell"
                                              "[[:alpha:]]"
                                              "[^[:alpha:]]"
                                              "[']"
                                              t
                                              ("-d" "de_DE"); Dictionary file name
                                              nil
                                              iso-8859-1))

(add-to-list 'ispell-local-dictionary-alist '("english-hunspell"
                                              "[[:alpha:]]"
                                              "[^[:alpha:]]"
                                              "[']"
                                              t
                                              ("-d" "en_US")
                                              nil
                                              iso-8859-1))

(setq ispell-program-name "hunspell"          ; Use hunspell to correct mistakes
      ispell-dictionary   "deutsch-hunspell") ; Default dictionary to use
```

`hunspell -D` gives:

```
 hunspell -D
SEARCH PATH:
.::/usr/share/hunspell:/usr/share/myspell:/usr/share/myspell/dicts:/Library/Spelling:/home/dw/.openoffice.org/3/user/wordbook:.openoffice.org2/user/wordbook:.openoffice.org2.0/user/wordbook:Library/Spelling:/opt/openoffice.org/basis3.0/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org/basis3.0/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.4/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.4/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.3/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.3/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.2/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.2/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.1/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.1/share/dict/ooo:/opt/openoffice.org2.0/share/dict/ooo:/usr/lib/openoffice.org2.0/share/dict/ooo
AVAILABLE DICTIONARIES (path is not mandatory for -d option):
/usr/share/hunspell/de_DE
/usr/share/hunspell/de_LU
/usr/share/hunspell/de_BE
/usr/share/hunspell/en_US
/usr/share/myspell/dicts/hyph_lt_LT
Can't open affix or dictionary files for dictionary named "en_AU".
```

I am working on an ubuntu 15.10 box with emacs 24.5.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insert below code into ~/.emacs or ~/.emacs.d/init,

```
(setq ispell-program-name "hunspell")
(setq ispell-local-dictionary "de_DE")
(setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist
      '(("de_DE" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" nil nil nil utf-8)))
```

AFTER above setup, you need turn on flyspell-mode by `(flyspell-mode 1)`.

Please make sure your dictionary is loaded properly. This is hunspell setup instead of Emacs setup.

<s>At Linux, you don't need extra setup (if your dictionaries are installed in a standard location).</s>

At other operating systems, here is the easiest way to hint hunspell where to search the dictionary.

You only need setup environment variable DICPATH by `export DICPATH=/usr/share/hunspell/de_DE` in Bash (At windows, you can setup environment variable through "Control Panel"). Both de_DE.dic and de_DE.aff should exist in that directory.

Or you just change your locale to de_DE

Comment: With this I get: `Error enabling Flyspell mode:
(ispell-phaf: No matching entry for nil.
)`

Comment: set environment variable DICPATH

Comment: I have set the DICTPATH in my .profile file and checked it in my emacs session via `getenv`. The directory `/usr/share/hunspell/` contains the file `de_DE.aff` and `de_DE.dic`. Howver I get the same error.

Comment: what's your OS? emacs version?

Comment: DICPATH is only needed for non-Linux OS. In your case, my original answer is enough. what you can do is re-install hunspell-de-de (maybe dictionary is broken?). Then use my setup at http://github.com/redguardtoo/emacs.d (maybe you mistakenly override emacs default setup?)

Comment: @I just pulled your .emacs.d and tested it. With that configuration flyspell worked, but I am not sure if it used hunspell since you seem to have conditional and use hunspell only if installed... Then I tried a minimal .emacs file with your code above but it doesn't work. Any idea for another minimal .emacs file to try?

Comment: My linux and emacs version are at the end of my original post.

Comment: yeah, I notice that, it should works out of the box on ubuntu. Check my previous comment, set your locale to de_DE and see what happens.

Comment: I re-read my notes on http://blog.binchen.org/posts/what-s-the-best-spell-check-set-up-in-emacs.html. It says the hunspell will always search the dictionary specified  by your locale (in your case, en_AU) even you don't use it. looks that dictionary is not installed.

Comment: Thanks now it works. There was also another problem: I had the line `(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'turn-on-flyspell)` before the dictionaries are setup. Moving this line below the dictionary definitions maked it work.

Comment: Yes, you'd better initialize the dictionary at the beginning of ~/.emacs, turn on flyspell in major-mode-hook.

Answer (score 2):

I compiled Emacs today (March 14, 2016) from git, version 25.1.50.1 for Windows 8.1, 64-bit. Run into the same issue. Found this answer by the indefatigable [Eli Zaretskii](http://gnu.emacs.bug.narkive.com/SafnPEMv/bug-19229-a-workaround-for-hunspell) and shortened the code for hunspell to this lines in my .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'exec-path "C:/cygwin64/usr/local/bin")
(setq ispell-program-name (executable-find "hunspell"))
(ispell-change-dictionary "de_DE" t)
```

OK, you see, hunspell was installed at the given path. I set the DICPATH variable to this locations as well. I set the DICTIONARY variable to "de_DE".

It was hard to find where hunspell stored the personal dictionary. I found it eventually at $HOME, the name of the file was `hunspell_de_DE`.

So it seems the whole installation is a lot easier nowadays.

Comment: This solved it for me on Emacs 26.1 on Windows 10. No need to play with the local dictionary when installing with http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files

Answer (score 0):

What causes the error `ispell-phaf: No matching entry ...` is the name `deutsch-hunspell`. By some reason `ispell.el` assumes that this is a **real** dictionary name and tries to locate corresponding files, namely `deutsch-hunspell.dic` and `deutsch-hunspell.aff` under `/usr/share/hunspell` directory.

That said, you should use only names found under `/usr/share/hunspell/` and only those of them that have an affix file (`.aff`) that are *base dictionaries* in hunspell terms (`man hunspell` for more details).

This does not mean however that if you specify `de_DE` hunspell will use `/usr/share/hunspell/de_DE.{dic,aff}` only. You can customize the exact set of dictionaries by means of `-d` option that will be passed to `hunspell`. For example, like this:

```
(setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist
      '(("de_DE" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']" t
         ("-d" "de_DE,de_med") nil iso-8859-1)))
```