# Emacs lisp throwing error when using spell check

Tags: debugging, ispell, hunspell

I am trying to configure Hunspell in my emacs running in windows. When I type `M-x ispell-buffer`, I get the following error:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp nil)
  string-match("," nil 0)
  split-string(nil "," t)
  ispell-parse-hunspell-affix-file(nil)
  ispell-find-hunspell-dictionaries()
  ispell-set-spellchecker-params()
  ispell-region(1 25)
  ispell-buffer()
  funcall-interactively(ispell-buffer)
  call-interactively(ispell-buffer record nil)
  command-execute(ispell-buffer record)
  execute-extended-command(nil "ispell-buffer" "ispell-bu")
  funcall-interactively(execute-extended-command nil "ispell-buffer" "ispell-bu")
  call-interactively(execute-extended-command nil nil)
  command-execute(execute-extended-command)
```

My `.emacs` file looks like this:

```
(setq exec-path (append exec-path '("D:/programs/emacs/hunspell/bin/")))

(setq ispell-program-name "hunspell")
;; below two lines reset the the hunspell to it STOPS querying locale!
(setq ispell-local-dictionary "en_US")
;; "en_US" is key to lookup in `ispell-local-dictionary-alist`
(setq ispell-local-dictionary-alist
      '(("en_US" "[[:alpha:]]" "[^[:alpha:]]" "[']"
     nil ("-d" "en_US") nil utf-8)))
```

Answer (score 1):

See [Hunspell flyspell and Emacs on windows](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/30008/hunspell-flyspell-and-emacs-on-windows)

Please figure out the version of hunspell you use. It supports either Windows style path or Unix style path but not both. Then setup environment variable `DICTPATH` properly.

Comment: Yes. I did it. I added the `DICPATH` varible in my `.emacs` file. Thanks. It's working now.